# How to change a part of the header name of a particular column to lowercase in ag-grid

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I tried used headerClass but it transformed the whole header name to lower case, but only want a part of it to be lowercase.

My Code:

{
field:"id",
headerName: 'RAJ(0P)'
}

I want only 0P part to become lowercase.

Any suggestions would help.

Update : I saw that one class is being applied to an external component which transforms the text into uppercase. So to overwrite that I guess I need to pass custom HTML to column header and apply a class which transforms it to lowercase.

So How to pass custom HTML to column header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `headerValueGetter` callback function to format the header text however you want. You need to add it to the column definition.

For your specific problem, you can use the following column definition (apologies if not refactored, wrote it quickly):

```
{
      field: "RAJ(0P)",
      headerValueGetter: function(params) {
        let headerName = params.colDef.field;
        let textWithinBracket = headerName.substring(headerName.indexOf('(') + 1, headerName.indexOf(')'));

        let lcTextWithinBracket = '(' + textWithinBracket.toLowerCase() + ')';

        let finalHeaderName = headerName.replace(/\(.*?\)/, lcTextWithinBracket)

        return finalHeaderName;
      }
    }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-qx9ucp?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: @RajatAggarwal My answer is still applicable. Your update is asking a new question.

Comment: @RajatAggarwal, have you tried Viquas's answer. Looks good to me

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using angular pipes?

in your html template when you are showing the value in let's say `span` you can do as follows to make your values capitalised

```html
<span>{{ value_expression | titlecase }}</span>
```

The reference link is here [TitleCasePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/TitleCasePipe)

Comment: They explicitly said they only want part of the name uppercased

Comment: Oh, I thought the "RAJ" has to become "Raj" for instance and thats exactly what the titlecase pipe does. It could be better if I could read tho.